# Java program end randomly with no error given

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

My program, which uses a BufferedWriter wrapped round a FileWriter keeps ending in a certain place every time I run it. I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Below is my code. I have pondered a memory leak, but I'm sure that throws an exception (unless I've stopped it from showing up, of course). And if it is supposed to be throwing an error, how do I solve it?
Thanks

```
import java.io.*;

public class BuffProcess {

static BufferedReader brOne, brTwo;
static FileReader inOne, inTwo;
//static FileInputStream fOne, fTwo;
static FileWriter out;
static BufferedWriter bw;
static StringBuffer sbOne, sbTwo;
static String stOne, stTwo, tech;
static char cOne, cTwo;
static boolean bOne, bTwo;
static int count, intOne, intTwo, intThree, intFour, intFive, intSix, maxSet, lineCount;
static int pCount, check;

public static void p(String s) {

    try {
        inOne = new FileReader(s + ".ck2");
        inTwo = new FileReader(s + ".ck2");
        brOne = new BufferedReader(inOne);
        brTwo = new BufferedReader(inTwo);
        out = new FileWriter(s + "_edit.ck2");
        bw = new BufferedWriter(out);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException");
    }

    stOne = "Start";
    stTwo = "Start";
    tech = "Pants";
    bOne = true;
    bTwo = false;
    count = 0;
    pCount = 929;

    try {

        while (stOne != null) { //For entire file
            lineCount++;
            //print("Lines processed=" + lineCount);
            stOne = brOne.readLine();
            brTwo.readLine();
            bw.write(stOne); bw.newLine();

            // Find settlements area of file
            if (stOne.contains("name=\"Vestisland\"")) { //Vestisland action (settlements section)

                for (int i = 2; i > 0; i--) {
                    stOne = brOne.readLine();
                    brTwo.readLine();
                    bw.write(stOne); bw.newLine();

                }

                stOne = brOne.readLine();
                brTwo.readLine();

                if (stOne.contains("max_settlements=")) {//For Vestisland only

                    while (bOne) { //Find tech levels
                        stTwo = brTwo.readLine();
                        count++;

                        if (stTwo.contains("technology=")) {

                            for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
                                stTwo = brTwo.readLine();
                                count++;
                            }
                            tech = stTwo;
                            bOne = false;
                        }
                    }
                    bOne = true;
                    maxSet();
                    bw.write(maxSetBlank + maxSet + "\n"); bw.newLine();
                    pCount--;
                    //print("Number of provinces remaining=" + pCount);
                    //print("Number of provinces done=" + (929 - pCount));
                    print("Vestisland" + ++check);

                    while (count !=0) {
                        brOne.readLine();

                        count--;
                    }
                }
                bw.flush();
                out.flush();

                while (pCount > 0) {// For provinces section
                    stOne = brOne.readLine();
                    //print(stOne);
                    brTwo.readLine();
                    bw.write(stOne); bw.newLine();

                    if (stOne.contains("name=")) {
                        names:
                        switch (stOne) {

                        case nullOne: case nullTwo: case nullThree: case nullFour: case nullFive:
                            print(test + "null");
                            pCount--;
                            //print("Number of provinces remaining=" + pCount);
                            //print("Number of provinces done=" + (929 - pCount));
                            print("Desert" + ++check);
                            break names;

                        default:

                            for (int i = 2; i > 0; i--) {
                                stOne = brOne.readLine();
                                brTwo.readLine();
                                bw.write(stOne); bw.newLine();
                            }

                            stOne = brOne.readLine(); print(stOne);
                            brTwo.readLine();

                            if (!stOne.contains("max_settlements")) {

                                while (bOne) { //Find tech levels
                                    stTwo = brTwo.readLine();
                                    count++;

                                    if (stTwo.contains("technology=")) {

                                        for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
                                            stTwo = brTwo.readLine();
                                            count++;
                                        }
                                        tech = stTwo;
                                        bOne = false;
                                    }
                                } //Find tech levels
                                bOne = true;
                                maxSet();
                                bw.write(maxSetBlank + maxSet + "\n"); bw.newLine();
                                bw.write(stOne); bw.newLine();
                                pCount--;
                                //print("Number of provinces remaining=" + pCount);
                                //print("Number of provinces done=" + (929 - pCount));
                                print("Without max_settlements" + ++check);
                            } else {

                                while (bOne) { //Find tech levels
                                    stTwo = brTwo.readLine();
                                    //print(stTwo);
                                    count++;

                                    if (stTwo.contains("technology=")) {

                                        for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
                                            stTwo = brTwo.readLine();
                                            //print(stTwo);
                                            count++;
                                        }
                                        tech = stTwo;
                                        bOne = false;
                                    }
                                }
                                bOne = true;
                                maxSet();
                                bw.write(maxSetBlank + maxSet + "\n"); bw.newLine();
                                pCount--;
                                //print("Number of provinces remaining=" + pCount);
                                //print("Number of provinces done=" + (929 - pCount));
                                print("With max_settlements" + ++check);
                            }
                            break names;
                        }
                }

            } //While provinces remain

                try {
                    while (stOne != null) {
                        bw.write(brOne.readLine()); bw.newLine();
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    stOne = null;
                }

        }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

    } finally {
        try { bw.close(); } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException");
        } finally { }
    }
    System.out.println("Provinces=" + pCount);
}

private static void maxSet() {
    int avg;
    intOne = Integer.parseInt(tech.substring(16, 17));
    intTwo = Integer.parseInt(tech.substring(18, 19));
    intThree = Integer.parseInt(tech.substring(22, 23));
    intFour = Integer.parseInt(tech.substring(24, 25));
    intFive = Integer.parseInt(tech.substring(30, 31));
    intSix = Integer.parseInt(tech.substring(46, 47));
    avg = Math.round((intOne+intTwo+intThree+intFour+intFive+intSix)/6);
    maxSet = avg + 2;
    //print(maxSet);
}

private static void print(Object o) {
    System.out.println(o);
}

static int pCheck = 0;
static String test = "This line is reached";
static final String maxSetBlank = "\t\tmax_settlements=";
static final String nullOne = "\t\tname=\"Western Sahara\"\n";
static final String nullTwo = "\t\tname=\"Adrar Plateau\"\n";
static final String nullThree = "\t\tname=\"Siberia\"\n";
static final String nullFour = "\t\tname=\"Sahara Desert\"\n";
static final String nullFive = "\t\tname=\"Sharawrah\"\n";
```

}

Comment: Where does it end unexpectedly?

Comment: Are you using an IDE like eclipse or netbeans?  Run in the debugger.

Comment: In your first catch blocks, you don't even exit the program...

Comment: you are catching nullpointerexceptions with empty catch blocks, this is very bad practice...

Comment: You need to supply additional information here.  Can you please provide the stack trace so that we can take a look at it?

Comment: @jgm Agreed. Unfortunately, there are no stack traces. Inserting `e.printStackTrace` or just droping the catch blocks would help.

Comment: Yep absolutely, the code needs to be altered so that every caught exception dumps a stacktrace.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it's throwing a NullPointerException which you are ignoring.

I would suggest removing *ALL* your exception catching and let the method `throws` these exceptions.  It is only worth catching an exception if you are going to do something useful with them.

BTW: I suspect none of your fields need to be static, I would make the local variables if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Your catch NullPointerException near the bottom isn't printing anything.

Word of advice...  Use an IDE that logs errors automatically, like Eclipse.  It will make your life about a billion times easier.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, but there's a NullPointerException at the end where it tries to assign null to a String (which is the condition for my while loop) and it doesn't work, so the while loop never ends. I use the NullPointerException to assign null to the String myself. Can't really think of any other way.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, print the stack traces in your catch blocks, for example, replace

```
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("IOException");
}
```

by

```
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And avoid catching exceptions without rethrowing or logging them. The problems that you currently face during debugging are the consequences.

By the way, if you don't know how to deal with an exception at one point, then don't catch it. For example, `IOException` generally should not be caught and ignored.

Also don't catch logical errors like `NullpointerException`, `IllegalStateException`, `IllegalArgumentException` or `AssertionError`. These are almost always programming mistakes. When you catch them and ignore them, you hide the problem but you haven't solve it.